# How to install webkitgtk1 on RHEL7

Tags: centos, rhel, webkit

I am running software on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 which requires `libwebkitgtk-1.0`. Unfortunately RHEL7 comes only with `webkitgtk3`. In contrast, RHEL6 had only `webkitgtk`. Other distributions like Debian, Ubuntu and openSuSE provide both versions of `webkitgtk`. Is there a way I could install the first version on RHEL7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download webkitgtk-2.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm for rhel7 for example from http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27127038/dir/redhat_el_7/com/webkitgtk-2.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html and then install by rpm -ihv webkitgtk-2.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

It need libsecret,libwebp, gstreamer1-plugins-base packages - yuu can install it from rhel7/centos7

Alternativly, but "right way" - yuu can add whole epel repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

And then install webkitgtk package by

```
yum install webkitgtk
```

Comment: `yum install epel-release` did not work but manually downloading and installing it worked. `webkitgtk` installed and my software works now. Thanks!

Comment: This was a perfect fix on my CentOS 7 box.

Comment: That command to install `epel-release` is there by default on CentOS *only*.  It's not available on RHEL systems.  For details, see [the fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 2):

I've traced this issue for almost two days and finally it works!

Here is the solution to install via yum when yum install epel-release doen't work for you.

add nux-dextop repo:

```
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

then install webkitgtk

```
yum install webkitgtk
```

you might hit 'y' twice to confirm you want to install webkitgtk from a third-party source.

Answer (score 1):

this is a good link as it led me to a workaround but is the advice still current? I can only see webkit3 and 4 in the latest CentOS 7 repo and not webkit1 or 2(and have installed epel as well)

```
Name        : webkitgtk3
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.4.11
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 11 M
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : GTK+ Web content engine library


Name        : webkitgtk4
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.16.6
Release     : 6.el7
Size        : 25 M
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
```

I manually downloaded and rpm installed webkitgtk-2.4.9-3.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm (from https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/webkitgtk-2.4.9-3.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html ) then used

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
export SWT_WEBKIT2=0
```

before launching the application and this worked, but it would be ideal if this could be achieved via yum?

```
# uname -a
Linux myhost 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cheers

Rod

Comment: is this a question or answer?

Comment: Its a bit of both. I am grateful to the original author for posting this and I am sure the first reply was correct at the time of writing. However since replying I have discovered that RedHat removed webkitgtk from the official repository. The link in the original article is broken so I provided the location where people can now download it as well as additional help in the form of SWT_GTK3 in case anyone wants to try this. My question is  - is manually installing the rpm the only method or is there another repo I am not aware of which will allow you to yum install it?